# Detecting deadlocks through code analisys

Tags: multithreading, deadlock

I've recently heard it is possible to detect at least some deadlocks only by analysis of syntax and semantics of the code. The topic was not discussed any further (and unfortunately there was no question-time given by the speaker) and my research through the Internet is far from statisfactory.

From what I understood the idea is to detect deadlocks *before* running the code, at the build level (so I am not talking about model-checking, which basically tries to simulate all of the possible states of our program to see if any deadlocks occur). If it is possible, then it could possibly be integrated with IDE's to inform about possible deadlocks before they could ever happen.

What are (if they are) those methods to detect deadlocks though code analisys? In which cases can a deadlock be detected at the code-writing level? And are those algorithms simple (and therefore fast) enough to be a more reasonable choice than model-checking or another run-time deadlock detection (which indeed can be costly sometimes)?

Comment: This will get much better answers if posted at cstheory.stackexchange.com. The idea probably does have something to do with simulating states.

Comment: If the formalism of CSP qualifies for you as 'code' then the FDR tool will find deadlocks, the way Millie above suggests, by checking all possible paths combined with some clever theory.

Comment: But then doesn't it just "simulate" the code? It would simply analyse it to follow the possible paths, which is a fair bit like "interpreting" the code instead of compiling it (considering a compiled language), am I right?